# Using a function to generate on object on a background thread using RxJava Observables

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java

I'm playing around with RxJava and trying to figure out how run a method on a background thread and deal with the results on the foreground thread.  I stumbled across a solution but wanted to get a sanity check and see if there was a better way, since there seem to be a lot of different ways to compose Observables to do similar things.

Here's what I have:

```
    Observable.defer(
        () -> Observable.just(
            // A. Should run on Scheduler.newThread
            db.query(
                false, DATABASE_TABLE, null,
                null, null, null, null, null,
                null)))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        Subscribers.create(
            // B. Should run on AndroidSchedulers.mainThread
            cursor -> adapter.swapCursor(cursor)
        ));
```

The code works as expected.  A runs on the background thread and B runs on the main thread.

My question is, this seems reasonable enough but is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defer` is a decent enough way to do it, but with the optional RxAsyncUtil lib, you can use the slightly nicer `fromFunc0`, like this:

```
Observable.fromFunc0(() -> db.query(...))
    .subscribeOn(... etc.
```

also, you don't have to use `Subscribers.create`, since one of the main overloads of subscribe takes a single action for `onNext`.

So, your subscribe could become:

```
    .subscribe(cursor -> { adapter.swapCursor(cursor) })
```

(not 100% sure if the `{}`s are necessary with the java8 lambdas. they may not be if swapCursor is void... try both?)

so, all together:

```
Observable.fromFunc0(() -> db.query(
    false, DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null, null))
    .scheduleOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(cursor -> { adapter.swapCursor(cursor) })
```

seems like a pretty tight implementation. :)